# How to prevent folder from being deleted or modified without using System.Security.DirectorySecurity?

Tags: c#, winforms

As I am searching about preventing the folder from being deleted or modified, I see only using `System.Security.DirectorySecurity`, which allows restricting access to certain users. And the problem is that a user(assuming that they logged in as a privileged user) can simply override the program by changing the settings back. I want to know if there are other ways that can prevent the folder from being deleted. I am new to programming.Hope u can help me with this.

Comment: What's your real goal here? If an application prevented me, as adminstrator, from deleting a folder on my machine, I'd call that malware.

Comment: I'm doing the project about private storage so I wanna make sure that the files or folder that store on my application is secure or can't delete after closing my application.

Comment: It's out of your control. On startup, validate what you find on the disk. If they deleted something you need, issue an error message. Imagine if developers could all run amok on *your* disk, locking you out of your own data on a whim. That would be intolerable.

Comment: You can encrypt your contents to make it difficult for users to tamper with the contents without you detecting it the next time the program runs.   But even running as administrator you can't create a rock that's too heavy for you to lift.